# Retrieve lost quicktime's record

Tags: mac, video, screen-capture, quicktime

I start recording my screen for two hours by clicking `cmd+shift+5`, after that I stopped the recording, and immediately a popped up video appear with an option to share recorded video, I click the share button and choose telegram and I clicked `done`, my video doesn't shared to telegram neither saved on default saving location, i.e. `desktop`.
I googled it but no solution work with me even [this one](https://osxdaily.com/2017/02/16/recover-lost-quicktime-recording-mac/)

Any solution will save my day, what I recorded very important to me.